# Android: Get intent and reroute it to another class

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is simple: if an intent object exists, I want to merely use that and add putExtra() and then startActivity to go back. However, I have no idea how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
Intent intent;
if(getIntent() != null) {
    intent = getIntent();
    //reroute to BarActivity class
} else {//this part is fine
    intent = new Intent(FooActivity.this, BarActivity.class);
}
intent.putExtra("cardHP", "100");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Your question is confusing... what are you trying to do? Go back where? Why? Are you returning from somewhere? Do you expect a result returned? What exactly are you wanting the intent to do? What's not working as expected?

Comment: i want to augment a key value pair to an intent provided it already exists.

Comment: intent.putExtra("cardHP", "100"); that is what this is... no? What is it not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: i need it to go back to the previous activity too. getIntent() does not take me back to the previous activity.

Comment: Are you sure that getIntent() contains what you expect it to contain? If it is not doing what you expect then it probably does not. If I am understanding you correctly now, the user is coming from another activity then you are attempting to get the intent that sent them there and then do something and then send them 'back' to the original activity. Is that correct?

Comment: Remember that your 'proxying' activity (that got original Intent) will still be in the back stack (when user presses Back he'll get to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use the startActivityForResult method, and detect the returned result on the onActivityResult method, then this works.

Answer (score 0):

getIntent() is a part of a larger chain. It will return the ENTIRE intent that was sent.

You can retrieve the calling class by using getIntent().getExtras().getString("TheOriginatingClass");

Edit: ok last time I edit this... I am too tired, need to go to sleep after this lol...
In the intent that was sent, there is the originating class and the class that is being called (Class1 and Class2). When you use the intent that was sent by Class1 you are essentially trying to call Class1 with the same intent that called Class2. You need to create a new intent and if you need the originating class (Class1) you can get that via the chain I described above.

Note: I forgot to add you will need to put the classname in as a string extra in the intent that is called from Class1. AFAIK there isn't a direct way to find out what the calling class was. I might be wrong about that though.

-or-

If you are using an int (as you are in your example) you could use startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)